# Recommendation for user synchronization between organization and external website

Tags: authentication, azure, social-networks

We are building a small social media platform for collaboration among a group of similar (but disparate) organizations. Each organization will have a small group of users who will be able to post content on this platform.

What would be the recommended ways for these users to create accounts on our social media platform? Our primary concern is if any member of the group leaves the parent firm, then his access should be revoked immediately from the platform too. He/she would obviously know the credentials, since he/she was a part of the entitled users earlier.

We are planning to host our platform on a cloud provider like MS Azure or AWS.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If only selected users from selected organizations can use the platform, can you use the infrastructure of those organizations to do the authentication (checking the credentials) and part of the authorization (is the account still active) for you? If not, how will you know that a user has left their firm?

Comment: I probably can, but that would require something to be available on the orgn's infrastructure. I was wondering if there is any way to perform an automatic sync between the organization's user activity and their user base on our platform. So if someone leaves the firm, the user base syncs up automatically on our platform.

Comment: Are you suggesting using SSO from the internal organization infrastructure? Something similar to Federated Identity?

Comment: I was not thinking of a particular technology, but I did have OAuth in the back of my mind. To do the automatic sync, you also need something on the org's infrastructure to sync with.

Comment: Thanks, i will investigate OAuth0 for this too.